# Error when testing pipeline: download data from sftp folder, parse it as json, update airtable records

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I am trying to set a pipeline, where the scripts are stored in Google Cloud, and lately, use CloudScheduler in order to execute each x minutes. The pipeline, accesses a sftp remote folder and downloads two xls files (first function module), that they are parsed to json format by a second module and finally the last module sends a patch request to airtable in order to update some records.
In cloudFunction, firstly I have tried to put the different function modules in separate files, but  i finally decided to put them in the same file main.py (in case that was an error), also with a requirements.txt (to install the dependencies).

The entry_point of the cloud_function is the function hello_world (the last one):

```
import os
import pysftp
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

def load_file_from_ftp(directory, filenames):
    '''
    Description: Connects to SFTP remote server, and downloads one or more xls files and reads them as dataframes
    Arguments:
        - 'dir'(string): path of the directory where the files are stored
        - 'filenames'(list): list of string, containing the name of the files to download
    Returns: 
        - 'found_files'(list): list of pandas dataframes
    '''
    # Import env vars
    HOSTNAME_SFTP = os.environ.get('HOSTNAME_SFTP')
    USERNAME_SFTP = os.environ.get('USERNAME_SFTP')
    PASSWORD_SFTP = os.environ.get('PASSWORD_SFTP')
    PORT_SFTP = int(os.environ.get('PORT_SFTP'))
    found_files = []
    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = None
    print(HOSTNAME_SFTP, USERNAME_SFTP, PASSWORD_SFTP, PORT_SFTP)
    
    with pysftp.Connection(HOSTNAME_SFTP, username=USERNAME_SFTP, password=PASSWORD_SFTP, port=PORT_SFTP, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
        print('Connected to SFTP server')
        # Get the list of files in the folder
        folders = sftp.listdir()
        print(folders)

        for xls_file in filenames:
            file = sftp.open(dir + xls_file)
            df_file = pd.read_excel(file)
            found_files.append(df_file)
        
    # Close the SFTP connection
    sftp.close()
    print("Disconnected from SFTP server")

    return found_files 

    def create_lists(df):
    '''
    Description: Creates a list of dictionaries with data from each political party data
    Arguments: 
        - 'df'(pd dataframe): dataframe where we will extract the data
    Returns:
        - 'llistes'(list): list of dictionaries for each political party
    '''
    llistes = [
        # Llista Nacional:
        {
            'id': 'recJeO0Mu4TSk8SPf',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[2,3] + df.iloc[13,3] + df.iloc[25, 3] + df.iloc[38, 3] + df.iloc[51,3] + df.iloc[65,3] + df.iloc[79, 3])
            } # DA
        },
        {
            'id': 'recX9CRRFH9yLkBFR',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[5,3] + df.iloc[16,3] + df.iloc[28, 3] + df.iloc[41, 3] + df.iloc[54,3] + df.iloc[68,3] + df.iloc[82, 3])
            } # PS
        },
        {
            'id': 'reckf2p3g2kcsJ4IZ',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[0,3] + df.iloc[11,3] + df.iloc[23, 3] + df.iloc[36, 3] + df.iloc[49,3] + df.iloc[63,3] + df.iloc[77, 3])
            } # Liberals
        },
        {
            'id': 'reca2Qzjta3qg5qkG',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[3,3] + df.iloc[14,3] + df.iloc[26, 3] + df.iloc[39, 3] + df.iloc[52,3] + df.iloc[66,3] + df.iloc[80, 3])
            } # Acció
        },
        {
            'id': 'recVi8I4tKcOL195J',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[4,3] + df.iloc[15,3] + df.iloc[27, 3] + df.iloc[40, 3] + df.iloc[53,3] + df.iloc[67,3] + df.iloc[81, 3])
            } # Endavant
        },
        {
            'id': 'recJFqscvqla4hWmn',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[1,3] + df.iloc[12,3] + df.iloc[24, 3] + df.iloc[37, 3] + df.iloc[50,3] + df.iloc[64,3] + df.iloc[78, 3])
            } # Concòrdia
        },

        # Llista Canillo:
        {
            'id': 'recuZj5NleyPBOwFS',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[8,3])
            } # DA
        },

        # Llista Encamp:
        {
            'id': 'recq1huYYFiVSUvlO',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[19,3])
            } # PS
        },
        {
            'id': 'recx8UlOslG8DMFjd',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[20,3])
            } # DA
        },

        # Llista Ordino:
        {
            'id': 'recpZRAwTHN56Sno1',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[32,3])
            } # DA
        },
        {
            'id': 'reciZPMzJRNPWFtkm',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[33,3])
            } # Endavant
        },
        {
            'id': 'recUpCyxtyCeBen2H',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[31,3])
            } # PS
        },

        # LLista Massana:
        {
            'id': 'rec29GlXXkvxB78kF',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[45,3])
            } # DA
        },
        {
            'id': 'recPW2138OYL6kckJ',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[44,3])
            } # PS
        },
        {
            'id': 'rectdl10pE4GfFAYk',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[46,3])
            } # Acció
        },

        # Llista Andorra:
        {
            'id': 'recEQMEpV19eTugiY',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[58,3])
            } # DA
        },
        {
            'id': 'recJe7rA61BCrgSaa',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[59,3])
            } # PS
        },
        {
            'id': 'recBqazmfwovNXE0l',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[57,3])
            } # Concòrdia
        },
        {
            'id': 'recOsly6lLoKoBbEr',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[60,3])
            } # Endavant
        },

        # Llista StJu:
        {
            'id': 'recGm4C2yrXdjticw',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[72,3])
            } # Endavant
        },
        {
            'id': 'recGgPJ0EcbtyT9k1',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[71,3])
            } # PS
        },
        {
            'id': 'recslIrVrRRx8AuDM',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[73,3])
            } # Concòrdia
        },
        {
            'id': 'recbodeJQrjUPKiNU',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[74,3])
            } # DA
        },

        # Llista Escaldes:
        {
            'id': 'recUvJudzNRNFgSRm',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[86,3]) 
            } # DA
        },
        {
            'id': 'rec5ndckdwnntcKcn',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[87,3])
            } # PS
        },
        {
            'id': 'rec0VLpjPRW2yDCw4',
            'fields': {
                'votes': int(df.iloc[85,3])
            } # Concòrdia
        },
    ]

    return (llistes)

def save_to_airtable(records):
    '''
    Description: Updates records in Airtable from dictionaries, parsed as json file
    Arguments:
        - 'records'(list): list of dictionaries with the records to be updated
    '''
    #Import env vars:
    AIRTABLE_API_URL = os.environ.get('AIRTABLE_API_URL')
    AIRTABLE_API_KEY = os.environ.get('AIRTABLE_API_KEY')

    # Define the headers for the request
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {AIRTABLE_API_KEY}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    #print(airtable_api_key, ' ', airtable_api_url)
    response = requests.patch(AIRTABLE_API_URL + '/lists', headers=headers, data=json.dumps({ 'records': records}))
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Record updated successfully")
    else:
        print("Error updating record: " + json.dumps(response.json()))

def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    # Define script parameters:
    remote_path = xxxx
    files_list = xxxx 

    files = load_file_from_ftp(directory=remote_path, filenames=files_list)
    '''
    df = files[0]
    lists = create_lists(df); print(lists)

    save_to_airtable(lists[:10])
    save_to_airtable(lists[11:21])
    save_to_airtable(lists[22:26])'''
    
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return f'Hello World!
```

'
Ir raises the following exception:

```
`500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
`
```

And in the logs, we obtain:

```
` File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()`
```

Comment: Can you fix your code formatting, it's difficult to read!

Comment: Yes, just done, sorry!

Comment: Your code is crashing. You will need the full stacktrace.

Comment: Indeed Error 500 is code crash, CLoud Logging stack trace can help to narrow the issue!